# Variable al volcar Select-string matches value sin valor

Tags: powershell

Estoy intentando realizar una comprobación de regex sobre un fichero de log de macos llamado systemextensions.txt.  El contenido del fichero, como ejemplo es el siguiente:

2 extension(s)
--- com.apple.system_extension.endpoint_security
enabled active  teamID  bundleID (version)  name    [state]
GT8P3H7SPW  com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension (10.7.6/1)  McAfee Network Extension    [terminated waiting to uninstall on reboot]

- - D3U2N4A6J7  com.protection.agent (02.00.07.1001/1.5.0)  com.protection.agent    [activated enabled]

Lo que intento, previo chequeo de que el tamaño del fichero es mayor de 0, es seleccionar la línea de extension(s) , sacar el valor numérico de la misma y ver si es mayor de 0 . En caso de que no lo sea saco mensaje de que no se han encontrado system extensions y e caso de serlo, saco el valor de las que esten enabled
El problema está en el momento en el que con el select-string intento sacar el valor numérico en una variable,ésta no me devuelve nada, aunque la línea sin variable sí que lo hace

$systemext = Get-ChildItem -Recurse systemextensions.txt

```
If ($systemext.Length -gt 0)
{
    $numext = Select-String $systemext.FullName -Pattern 'extension(s)' -SimpleMatch | Select-String -Pattern '\d'
    If ($numext.Matches.value -eq 0) {$WorkSheet.Cells.Item(30,3) = "No system extensions found"}
    else {$extenabled = Select-String $systemext.FullName -Pattern 'activated enabled'}
}
```

Lo he intentado con las siguientes líneas(modificando el if posterior) y las variables resultan vacías:

1-.

$numext = Select-String $systemext.FullName -Pattern 'extension(s)' -SimpleMatch | Select-String -Pattern '\d' | foreach {$_.Matches.Value}

y
2-.

cambiando $numext a $numext = Select-String $systemext.FullName -Pattern 'extension(s)' -SimpleMatch

para luego :
$prueba = ($numext | Select-String -Pattern '\d').Matches.Value

Answer (score 0):

Encontrada la solución:
He dado el siguiente valor a la variable $numext:

$numext = (Select-String -Path $systemext.FullName -Pattern '^(?:\d+) (?=extension(s))').Matches.Groups[0].Value

de esta forma el valor devuelto es 2 y con ello puede hacer la comparación del valor numérico necesario para proseguir con la lógica del script.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).